R can no longer read special characters
Since updating R to R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt)" Rstudios is no longer able to read special characters like ý or í. There is a similar question from 7 years ago without an accepted answer. How can I fix this? Thanks.
Link similar question:
How to solve problem with special characters such as "é" with R and RStudio?



LocationId
Location




1
Zadní


2
Brno -Straý Lískovec



saved as loc.csv
locations <- read.table("data/loc.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)


Where exactly are you having issues? Why not link to the "similiar question"?

Sorry, what do you mean where am I having issues? The issue is that R can't read special characters while it could using 4.1.2

Please show an example with code that worked before and is now giving bad results.

Thanks, that helps a lot. Now what are you seeing, are the special characters replaced by question marks? It's important to know since that may lead to the answer. Posting the result of e.g. dput(read.table("data/loc.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)) would show the exact data frame that is generated. Also do you get the same result when starting and working with R from the console without RStudio?

That was indeed the case. I already fixed it and gave the answer for the next one. Issue was that it was not UTF 8, thanks anyway

Good to see you solved it. A bit odd because it worked before but still glad it works now!

there are many cases of "it worked (yesterday/last week/with the old version) but doesn't now" where the OP is accidentally doing something slightly different than they did (yesterday/last week/with the old version). I wouldn't be sure this is really due to a version difference until I had a reproducible example.

It looks like an encoding issue. If you know the file encoding of the CSV file you can include is as a parameter in the read.table()
For example (this assumes the file is encoded with Latin1):
locations <- read.table("data/loc2.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE, encoding = "latin1")


If anyone else has this issue, use spreadsheet program to save the file as UTF 8
